# Symbol stringification?

Tags: smart-contract, symbol-name

an action in my contract accepts an asset:

```
void token::burn(asset a)
```

which I want to print out:

```
printf("Asset [%s] burnt\n", a.symbol.to_string());
```

except the `symbol` class does not offer stringification.  there's a `print` method but that's not what I need as I want a string I can embed elsewhere

this seems like pretty basic functionality.  how is this done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the answer turns out to be:

```
printf("Asset [%s] burnt\n", a.symbol.code().to_string().c_str());
```

thanks to @aarin_hagerty on https://t.me/joinchat/Esi1OkPktgcFeJ3Lmlcrqg for the answer

Comment: Thank you for posting the answer here, even though you got the answer elsewhere!